# JQuery Only Toggle if checkbox gets checked .. possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the code below where it toggles between 2 div's.
My problem is that I'm using a checkbox to trigger the toggle.
What I need is that...

If the checkbox is NOT check and the user checks it ... then it toggles but if the checkbox is already checked then do not toggle.

Is this possible at all?

Current code is below:

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(function(){
      $('.togglelink').click(function(){
         $('#one').toggle();
         $('#two').toggle(); 
      });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: write an if condition and check the value of ur checkbox. If it false execute ur toggle function else do nothing...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about adding that ?

```
$('.togglelink').click(function(){
    if($(this).attr('checked')) {
        return false;
    }else{
         $('#one').toggle();
         $('#two').toggle(); 
    }
 });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
  $('.togglelink').click(function(){       if (!($('.togglelink').attr('checked'))) {
     $('#one').toggle();
     $('#two').toggle(); 
   }
  });
});
```